# Why SDK must config in every project Android?

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

```
An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:

  1.  Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-33.

      Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdk
      of at least 34, for example 34.

      Note that updating a library or application's compileSdk (which
      allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
      targetSdk (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
      minSdk (which determines which devices the app can be installed
      on).
```

How to completely fix this error. Don't need config in Gradle for each project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsvNr.png)

I config Gradle file from sdk 33 -> 34. and It ok. But I don't want config for other project

Comment: Please don't post text like Gradle config as screenshot. Just copy and paste the relevant text sections and format it as code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Studio Iguana or Hedgehog

[Android Studio Beta or Canary Build](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview?hl=en)